# How to place elements with same class on a column and different rows with css grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a question "choice/match" and I need to put choices in a column and matches in an other column with grid css, my problem is the match column is overlapping.
 
This is how it looks like right now :

```css
.grid{
  display:grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap:12px;
}

.grid>div{
  padding:12px;
  margin:0;
  color:#fff;
  background:#222;
}

.choice{
  grid-column-start: 1;
}
.match{
  grid-column-start:2;
  grid-row-start:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
 <div class="choice">Choice 1</div>
 <div class="choice">Choice 2</div>
 <div class="choice">Choice 3</div>
 <div class="match">Match 1</div>
 <div class="match">Match 2</div>
 <div class="match">Match 3</div>
</div>
```

If I remove `grid-row-start` it starts from the second line. 
FIY this is just an example, the question have a dynamic equal number of matches and columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `grid-auto-flow: dense`

```css
.grid{
  display:grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  gap:12px;
}

.grid>div{
  padding:12px;
  margin:0;
  color:#fff;
  background:#222;
}

.choice{
  grid-column-start: 1;
}
.match{
  grid-column-start:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
 <div class="choice">Choice 1</div>
 <div class="choice">Choice 2</div>
 <div class="choice">Choice 3</div>
 <div class="match">Match 1</div>
 <div class="match">Match 2</div>
 <div class="match">Match 3</div>
</div>
```